# Python plotly: bars hardly visible from background

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to build a default bar chart in plotly using Plotly express (imported as `px`). However, the default (and manually chosen) colors hardly differ from the background. The legend will show appropriate colors.

edit: The very basic call
`px.bar(credit_cards, x='Marital_Status')`
will give similar if not less visible results.

An image of the Notebook
[is attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OwBS.png)
Thanks in advance!

Edit/kind of solution: using `px.histogram` instead of `px.bar` displays bright colors. I would still be interested in what is wrong with bar, though.

Comment: The y-axis is not specified. If I specify it, will it change?

Comment: Specifying the y axis with some other variable will add lines for these observations, but will not change the overall visibility.

Comment: @Tuzzler what does px refer to? plotly?

Comment: yes, sorry, I will state this more clearly in the original post

Comment: The x-axis is a categorical variable. Is it the same if I switch to the sample go in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#basic-bar-chart-with-plotlygraphobjects)?

Comment: If I use lists with the respective categories and counts as inputs for x and y it works. However, I was hoping not to need to create a list with the count of occurrences myself. (Just the way `histogram` does it). Maybe that's just the way in plotly...